# Flutter: How to fit the web view size to screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am new in flutter,

tried to use web view in flutter, but the the size of the web view is bigger than the screen.

I want to fit the web page size to the phone screen size.

How I can do that?

Here is what I get now:

[image]

I want to see:

[image]

Here is my code:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

```
class CoursesInformation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<CoursesInformation> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  var urlString = "https://shoham.biu.ac.il/BiuCoursesViewer/MainPage.aspx";

  launchUrl() {
    setState(() {
      urlString = controller.text;
     flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl(urlString);
       flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(urlString,
              rect: new Rect.fromLTWH(
                  0.0, 
                  0.0, 
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 
                  300.0));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged wvs) {
      print(wvs.type);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('מידע על קורסים'),
        centerTitle: true
      ),
      url: urlString,
      withZoom: true,
      scrollBar: true,
      withJavascript: true,
      useWideViewPort: true,

      withLocalStorage: true,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

In your case, you can enable the `DESKTOP` mode (as it happens on normal browsers like Chrome, etc.) through the option `preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP`

Here is an example with your URL:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl:
                "https://shoham.biu.ac.il/BiuCoursesViewer/MainPage.aspx",
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  debuggingEnabled: true,
                  preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {

            },
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I getting error when import: import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart'

Comment: @einav Have you installed the plugin? Or have you just copied and pasted the code? You need to add `flutter_inappwebview` dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: I add   flutter_inappwebview: ^3.3.0
to pubspec.yaml file

Comment: If you have any other issue or error, you can post it in the issue section of the [flutter_inappwebview github repository](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)

Comment: I  am getting this error:  [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to use platform views with API 19, required API level is: 20

Comment: after I succeed to use the import above. now I see a white screen

Comment: please @einav, read the documentation and requirements of the plugin. It is clearly written that [`InAppWebView `](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#inappwebview-class) requires Android 20+. This is the minimum Android version if you want to use `InAppWebView` widget. Unfortunately, this doesn't depend on me but on the official [`AndroidView `](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AndroidView-class.html) API to embed native view inside the Flutter widget tree. If you need support lower Android version, then you should use `InAppBrowser` or `ChromeSafariBrowser`.

Comment: Using this plugin with this option requires support to iOS 13+ only.

Comment: `flutter_inappwebview` has a lot of issues & is not maintained these days. https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues

Answer (score 1):

I used `InAppWebView and it works for me.  This will add a line like this to your package's` pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
```

For example:

```
return InAppWebView(
      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
              useHybridComposition: true,
              textZoom: 100 * 2 // it makes 2 times bigger
          )
      ),
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
        webViewController = controller;
      },
    );
```

If you want to make it smaller, you just need to divide it as below:

```
textZoom: 100 / 2 // it makes 2 times smaller
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
useWideViewPort: true,
```

Read more documentation at https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_webview_plugin/latest/

It now looks like

[image]

Comment: Check the screenshot

Comment: What about using webview_flutter 0.3.22+1 instead of flutter_webview_plugin

Comment: the screenshot is still bigger, i want to see the full page